# XmlDocument and line breaks

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing

I parse XML text read from embedded resource using XmlDocument.Load(). There are text elements containing multiple lines. I have read that XML parser is supposed to normalize line breaks turning CR-LF pairs into single LF characters. But I found that it does not in some cases. More weird is that sometimes it does normalization and I cannot figure out what this behavior depends on. We have some unit tests depending on this behavior and they pass on some machines and fail on other ones and different programs on the same machine behave differently. What I am missing?

Here is a simple test program which in my case always shows that both CR and LF are preserved literally. (But the unit test I mentioned passes on the same machine indicating that line feeds are normalized). Setting PreserveWhitespace does not make a difference.

```
 asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
 res = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("test.xml");
 var doc = new XmlDocument();
 var reader = new StreamReader(res);
 doc.Load(reader);
 var root = doc.DocumentElement;
 var text = root.InnerText;
 var cr = text.IndexOf('\r');
 var lf = text.IndexOf('\n');
 Console.WriteLine("CR:{0} LF:{1}", cr, lf);
```

Comment: Is it a difference in the underlying MSXML.dll installed on the machine, actually now that I mention it I am not sure that the runtime uses the MSXML*dlls?

Comment: As a sanity check, you should save the output of the SteamReader as text and compare it on a working and non-working machine.  That way, you'll know the problem is in the XmlDocument and not further 'upstream'.

Comment: As I mentioned sometimes working and non-working machine is the same one so there is something else that makes a difference. I tried output from StreamReader (using ReadToEnd) and it contains all control characters literally. I am not sure whether this should be considered wrong or not (Microsoft documentation says nothing about it).

Answer (score 2):

If you want normalization, you have to pass an [`XmlReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance to the `XmlDocument.Load` function be sure:

```
asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
res = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("test.xml");
var doc = new XmlDocument();
var reader = new StreamReader(res);
var xmlreader = XmlReader.Create(reader)
doc.Load(xmlreader);
```

`XmlReader` lists that it does do normalization in the [Data conformance section on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#xmlreader_data).

When I look up the [Load methods in the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml/System/Xml/Dom/XmlDocument.cs.html#46770177eca17a37), it appears that XmlDocument's overloaded convenience `Load` methods use a `XmlTextReader`, whose [`Normalization` property defaults to false](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.normalization%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

When I looked at [.NET Core's version of `XmlDocument`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Xml.XmlDocument/src/System/Xml/Dom/XmlDocument.cs#L899), the `Load` functions use a plain `XmlReader` instead. This may indicate that the internal code was at some point changed, and it might explain some of the weird behaviour you've seen for apparently similar code.

This behaviour of `XmlDocument` is not documented on MSDN, which is why I bumped into it when calculating digests.